# Where is res/drawable/Icon.png located in Titanium Studio IDE?

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I keep getting this error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  res/drawable/Icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I'm trying to located that icon.png so that I can rename it. After using trial and error renaming a lot of png's I give up trying to locate it.
NOTE: I am using titanium 3.2.3GA. I am trying to run/install the app on an Android tablet (nexus 10). The app is cross platform though.

EDIT: Thanks to @Dragon, I found the file I was looking for. But after changing the name I get this new error:

```
[ERROR] :  Failed to package application:
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  /Users/ebads/Desktop/workspace/MYPROJECT/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/Icon').
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

I hate Titanium studio.

EDIT 2: I made a change in the xml, going to run and see if it works.

Comment: You need to post some code example to get solution for your problem.

Comment: Code is proprietary. But I don't understand how my code will solve it. I just need to know what folder hierarchy Titanium studio is referring to.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder? "res" is auto generated.

Comment: @JosiahHester I did, many times

Comment: Are you getting this error during install? Or at compile time?  And: what is proprietary on some code lines which try to grab an image from drawable?

Comment: @greenapps, its during install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find it at

```
Titanium_studio_workspace/YOUR_APP/build/android/res/drawable
```

Just change the icon name from `Icon.png` to `icon.png`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahaa .. Good catch... Capitals not allowed. `I'm trying to located that icon.png so that I can rename it.` I should have asked him why he would.

Comment: @Dragon Thank you, I was frying my brain looking for this. But after changing the name I now get another error: [ERROR] :  /Users/ebads/Desktop/workspace/MYPROJECT/build/android/AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/Icon').

Comment: I made a change in the xml file. I am now running to see if it works.

Comment: I don't see how this is the answer, even if you rename Icon.png in the build folder to icon.png, next time you build your app it's going to overwrite it with Icon.png again and error.

Answer (score -3):

```
res/drawable/Icon.png: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
```

The error tells all. You see

```
res/drawable/Icon.png
```

contains unallowed / characters. It is not a single filename as it is a path containing foldernames. You will have this 'filename' somewhere in your code. Change to `Icon.png` or `Icon` only.

Comment: Yes I know. If you fully read my question, I said that I was trying to look for the res/drawable directory path in titanium so  I can change it.

Comment: If you fully read my comment then you would know that I wanted to know why you would. As you did not tell. You left that to the reader. Well you know what happened...